# Atualizar imagens sem a necessidade de atualizar o site inteiro

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando um código javascript que atualiza a foto do locutor(a) de acordo com o dia da semana e o horário que ele(a) está no ar. Porém isto só acontece quando a página é atualizada (F5). Gostaria de saber o que preciso acrescentar no código para a atualização das imagens acontecerem de forma automática, sem que seja necessária a atualização de todo o site? 
Segue abaixo o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>

    function rodarImagens(){
            var current = new Date();
            var agora = current.getDay();
            var hora = current.getHours();
            var minutos = current.getMinutes();

            switch (agora){
                    case 0: //domingo
                            if(hora >= 0 && hora < 6){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 6 && hora < 9){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 18){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                    break
                    case 1: //segunda
                            if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');} 
                            if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                    break
                    case 2: //terça
                            if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');} 
                            if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                    break
                    case 3: //quarta
                            if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');} 
                            if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                    break
                    case 4: //quinta
                            if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');} 
                            if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                    break
                    case 5: //sexta
                           if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');} 
                            if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                    break                   
                    case 6: //sábado
                            if(hora >= 0 && hora < 8){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 8 && hora < 10){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador .png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 10 && hora < 12){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor5.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                            if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ document.write('<img src="/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;"/>');}
                    break   
            }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<p><script>rodarImagens();</script></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sobre melhorias no código**

Não aconselho usar `document.write`, pois vai apagar o site e manter só a foto, o melhor seria que cada imagem tivesse sua *ID* e você trocasse por uma função semelhante.
Eu também notei que o domingo todo é apenas o operador, não entendi por que colocou o mesmo pra cada intervalo de horário, não bastava por o período todo? Assim:

```
if(hora >= 0 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
```

**Como rodar a função em modo automático e disparar sozinho**

User `setTimeout` para repetir o chamado da função a cada segundo e se trocar o horário ele troca a imagem:
Modifique a Tag `BODY` assim:

```
<body onload="rodarImagens()">
```

Dentro da função rodarImagens() no final, mas dentro, coloque isso:

```
setTimeout(function(){ rodarImagens() }, 1000);
```

Código completo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script>

        function rodarImagens(){
                var current = new Date();
                var agora = current.getDay();
                var hora = current.getHours();
                var minutos = current.getMinutes();

                var locutor = document.getElementById('locutor');
switch (agora){
                        case 0: //domingo
                                if(hora >= 0 && hora < 6){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 6 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 17 && hora < 18){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                        break
                        case 1: //segunda
                                if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
                                if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png"}
                                if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"}
                                if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"} 
                                if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                        break
                        case 2: //terça
                                if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
                                if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png"}
                                if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"}
                                if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"} 
                                if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                        break
                        case 3: //quarta
                                if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
                                if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png"}
                                if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"}
                                if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"} 
                                if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                        break
                        case 4: //quinta
                                if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
                                if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png"}
                                if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"}
                                if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"} 
                                if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                        break
                        case 5: //sexta
                               if(hora >= 0 && hora < 7){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 7 && hora < 9){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 9 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
                                if(hora >= 12 && hora < 14){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor2.png"}
                                if(hora >= 14 && hora < 16){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos < 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if (hora == 16 && minutos >= 40){locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"}
                                if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor4.png"} 
                                if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                        break                   
                        case 6: //sábado
                                if(hora >= 0 && hora < 8){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 8 && hora < 10){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador .png"}
                                if(hora >= 10 && hora < 12){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor1.png"}
                                if(hora >= 12 && hora < 13){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                                if(hora >= 13 && hora < 17){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor5.png"}
                                if(hora >= 17 && hora < 19){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/locutor3.png"}
                                if(hora >= 19 && hora < 24){ locutor.src = "/site103fm/imagenshorario/operador.png"}
                        break   
                }
                setTimeout(function(){ rodarImagens() }, 1000);
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="rodarImagens()">
<img src="" id="locutor" style="right:6px;margin-top:7px;position: absolute; z-index: 99999999;" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Resolvido! Está funcionando como eu queria. A imagem do locutor atualiza automaticamente sem que o site precise ser atualizado. E agora o site não desaparece após o tempo estabelecido em setTimeout. Obrigado!